# translate panda dataframe using dictionary sorted by word length

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, translate

I have imported an excel to a pandas dataframe, which I'm trying to translate and then export back to an excel.

For example purpose say this is my data set:

````
d = {"cool":"chill", "guy":"dude","cool guy":"bro"}```
data = [['cool guy'], ['cool'], ['guy']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['WORDS'])


print(df)
#    WORDS   
# 0  cool guy   
# 1  cool  
# 2  guy
````

So the easiest solution would be to use pandas built in function replace. However if you use:

```
df['WORDS'] = df['WORDS'].replace(d, regex=True)
```

The result is:

```
print(df)
#    WORDS   
# 0  chill dude   
# 1  chill  
# 2  dude
```

(cool guy doesn't get translated correctly)

This could be solved by sorting the dictionary by the longest word first. I tried to use this function:

```
import re
def replace_words(col, dictionary):
    # sort keys by length, in reverse order
    for item in sorted(dictionary.keys(), key = len, reverse = True):
        col = re.sub(item, dictionary[item], col)
    return col
```

But..

```
df['WORDS'] = replace_words(df['WORDS'], d)
```

Results in a type error:
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Trying to convert the row to a string did not help either

```
...*
col = re.sub(item, dictionary[item], [str(row) for row in col])
```

Does anyone have any solution or different approach I could try?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding don't you just want `replace` without regex? `df['WORDS'] = df['WORDS'].replace(d)`

Comment: I think you need `df['WORDS'].replace(dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k: len(k[0]), reverse=True)), regex=True)`.

Comment: @HenryEcker I seem to have misunderstood the need for regex. Simply replace(d) was enough, as you said! Thank you!

Comment: @HenryYik Your solution worked as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `replace`

```
df.WORDS.replace(d)
Out[307]: 
0      bro
1    chill
2     dude
Name: WORDS, dtype: object
```

Comment: replace(d) was enough for it to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.map` and pass the dictionary. It will replace the values in the column from the dictionary if it is found in the key of the dictionary being passed.

```py
>>> df['WORDS'].map(d)
0      bro
1    chill
2     dude
Name: WORDS, dtype: object
```

Comment: This doesn't work because If there is a word in the df that is not in the dictionary, it gets replaced with NaN.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['WORDS'] = df['WORDS'].apply(lambda x: d[x])
```

This will do the work.

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a word in the df that is not in the dictionary. It causes a key error.